# Out of stack - Internet Explorer - WebAppBuilder

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, dojo, internet-explorer

I'm developing a viewer with ESRI WebAppBuilder. I have a widget that use a table programatically created with component dojox.grid.DataGrid.

When Internet Explorer (version 11) renders datagrid with this code grid.startup(), I am getting "Stack overflow at line 0".

Do you know how to debug/fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using dgrid or gridx? From the DataGrid [docs](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html), "Beginning with Dojo 1.7, you should use dgrid or gridx, next-generation grid components that take full advantage of modern browsers and object stores."